# Reading Table of String Data to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have been trying different attempts at converting my table of string data to a pandas dataframe. Every time I try to convert, the result is a dataframe with 1 column but the 1 column is all the data grouped into one column and I need it separated into 13 columns (1 year col, and 12 month columns).

My string table data looks like this in the string variable: dfs --->

```
    1949    0.533    1.151    1.146    1.057    0.316    0.730    0.752    0.535    0.053   -0.161    1.439    0.288
0   1950    0.732    0.883    1.743    0.781    0.574    1.068    0.738    0.173   -0.006    0.098    0.669    0.919
1   1951    1.460    0.593    0.980    0.847    0.807    0.729    0.751    0.298    0.305   -0.130    0.701    1.257
2   1952    1.330    1.525    1.296    0.626    0.854    1.219    0.550    0.486   -0.096    0.534    0.395    1.296
3   1953    1.664    1.601    0.977    1.383    0.722    0.598    0.656    0.490    0.345   -0.088    0.398    1.630
4   1954    1.160    1.591    1.494    0.354    0.365    0.832    0.753    0.728    0.076    0.136    0.679    1.214
5   1955    2.151    0.294    1.818    0.957    0.835    0.899    0.575    0.131   -0.199    0.566    1.734    1.273
6   1956    1.276    1.585    1.434    1.125    0.349    0.733    0.922    0.994    0.009   -0.084    0.494    1.418
7   1957    1.392    0.715    1.546    0.539    0.536    0.810    0.980    0.427    0.295   -0.070    0.838    1.306
8   1958    1.340    2.298    0.751    0.755    0.363    1.034    1.030    1.131    0.520    0.356    1.402    1.136
9   1959    1.838    1.471    1.578    0.970    0.683    0.858    0.589    0.515    0.130    0.518    0.462    0.606
10  1960    1.628    1.526    1.344    1.013    0.734    0.841    0.856    0.822   -0.073    0.847    1.190    1.090
11  1961    1.526    1.422    1.487    1.759    0.537    0.905    0.841    0.396    0.157    0.484    0.861    1.876
12  1962    1.515    0.895    1.339    1.080    0.668    0.589    1.063    0.621    0.274    0.698    0.832    1.307
13  1963    1.277    1.806    1.531    1.517    0.615    1.045    0.920    0.537   -0.356    0.334    1.181    1.512
```

My best attempt at converting it into a 13 column dataframe is this -

```
string_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dfs))
```

or this gives a similar incorrect result:

```
string_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dfs), sep=",")
```

I need the final "string_df" to look like my data above but in 13 columns, not 1 column.

Here is a snapshot of my strange looking df with 1 column and I try to reset_index and it still is not formatted correctly.

[image]

Comment: The dataframe shape in the first image is (9, 14). Can you tell me what is required?

Comment: sure, the row starting at index "0" or year 1950 is perfect ending at row index == 13 or year 1963 and then 13 columns also. i do not need the extra index column so it can be dropped.  thank you,

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply work the string using python string methods and construct a dataframe from the result.

```py
data = """
    1949    0.533    1.151    1.146    1.057    0.316    0.730    0.752    0.535    0.053   -0.161    1.439    0.288
0   1950    0.732    0.883    1.743    0.781    0.574    1.068    0.738    0.173   -0.006    0.098    0.669    0.919
1   1951    1.460    0.593    0.980    0.847    0.807    0.729    0.751    0.298    0.305   -0.130    0.701    1.257
2   1952    1.330    1.525    1.296    0.626    0.854    1.219    0.550    0.486   -0.096    0.534    0.395    1.296
3   1953    1.664    1.601    0.977    1.383    0.722    0.598    0.656    0.490    0.345   -0.088    0.398    1.630
4   1954    1.160    1.591    1.494    0.354    0.365    0.832    0.753    0.728    0.076    0.136    0.679    1.214
5   1955    2.151    0.294    1.818    0.957    0.835    0.899    0.575    0.131   -0.199    0.566    1.734    1.273
6   1956    1.276    1.585    1.434    1.125    0.349    0.733    0.922    0.994    0.009   -0.084    0.494    1.418
7   1957    1.392    0.715    1.546    0.539    0.536    0.810    0.980    0.427    0.295   -0.070    0.838    1.306
8   1958    1.340    2.298    0.751    0.755    0.363    1.034    1.030    1.131    0.520    0.356    1.402    1.136
9   1959    1.838    1.471    1.578    0.970    0.683    0.858    0.589    0.515    0.130    0.518    0.462    0.606
10  1960    1.628    1.526    1.344    1.013    0.734    0.841    0.856    0.822   -0.073    0.847    1.190    1.090
11  1961    1.526    1.422    1.487    1.759    0.537    0.905    0.841    0.396    0.157    0.484    0.861    1.876
12  1962    1.515    0.895    1.339    1.080    0.668    0.589    1.063    0.621    0.274    0.698    0.832    1.307
13  1963    1.277    1.806    1.531    1.517    0.615    1.045    0.920    0.537   -0.356    0.334    1.181    1.512
"""
df = pd.DataFrame({int(li[0]): li[1:] for li in (s[3:].split() for s in data.split('\n')) if li}, dtype=float)
```

[image: res]

---

A more convoluted way is to use `StringIO` along with `read_csv`. The resulting frame will need to be worked a lot more to be reshaped into the correct shape.

```py
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='  +', engine='python').T.reset_index()
df.columns = df.iloc[0].astype(int)
df = df.drop([0]).reset_index(drop=True)
df[1949] = df[1949].astype(float)
```